# Is 'Bower package management system' is now obsolete? What are the replacement of Bower (static content manager for client-site Web App)?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, bower

I am using 'Visual Studio 2019' and doing an 'ASP.NET Core 3.1' project. I was going to use

> Bower package management system.

for my project. But then I saw that isn't included in the templates. Then while researching I found out that I can add that manually. And I also saw some saying that 'it is now obsolete and we should not use that'. There is a link:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/what-happened-to-bower/.

So, I need the best suggestion about how to go from here.

1. Should I set up the dependencies manually of 'Bower package management system' and use it in my project?
2. Should I install Bootstrap from 'NuGet Package Manager'? As, I was about to install Bootstrap with Bower.
3. Should I use an alternative of Bower? if 'yes' then suggest some packages similar to that.
4. Should I install Bower from NuGet? What does that package do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I set up the dependencies manually of 'Bower package management
>   system' and use it in my project?

**Actually**, Since VS2017 and later, ASP.NET Core projects abandoned **Bower** system. Instead, not only Microsoft but also [Bower itself](https://bower.io/) suggests we should use `npm Yarn` or `Webpack`.

[image]

So if you still use Bower in your new project, you may encounter various compatibility issues, so we do not recommend you to use it in **vs2019**.

> Should I install Bootstrap from 'NuGet Package Manager'? As, I was
>   about to install Bootstrap with Bower.

To install Bootstrap in VS 2019 project, nuget is a right way. So what you thought is right.

**With nuget**, additional parameters can be configured into the project according to the author's needs while installing the package, so using **Nuget** is more convenient and convenient.

Right-click on your project-->`Manage Nuget pacakges`--> search `Bootstrap` and install it.

> Should I use an alternative of Bower? if 'yes' then suggest some
>   packages similar to that.

Please try to use `Yarn`, `Webpack` or `Parcel` rather than `Bower`.

> Should I install Bower from NuGet? How does that package do?

The **Bower** package was last released in 2014 and after that, the official has announced to give up that package. It is just left as an outdated product on **Nuget**.

[image]

So you do not need to install that package but to use the new package just as I recommend.

Comment: can you answer the 4th point again? About what are the functionalities of the package.

Comment: Can 'LibMan' be used? Is it the perfect replacement without extra harassment?

Comment: In the past, Bower nuget package can easily install the bower system for your project. In fact, it is the bower system, but it is more convenient to use nuget, but the automatic official website deprecates bower, and the nuget package is outdated.

Comment: LibMan is also a new feature for this. You  can use use it for your project.